# TypeScript doesn't recognize my jest mock module

Tags: typescript, mocking, jestjs

Suppose I have an `index.ts` that will import `Database.ts` and run some queries. To test this `index.ts` file, I want to mock the `Database.ts` because I don't want to connect to any real database.

This is my `index.ts`:

```
import { connect } from './Database'

export async function runSomeQuery() {
  const connection = await connect()
  const result = await connection.query('SOME QUERY')
  return result
}
```

and here is the mock of database (`__mocks__/Database.ts`)

```
const mockConnection = {
  query: jest.fn()
}

export const connect = jest.fn(
  () => Promise.resolve(mockConnection)
)

export function __getMockConnection() {
  return mockConnection
}
```

you can see that I expose a `__getMockConnection` so that I can get the `mockConnection` in my tests (`index.spec.ts`) (this pattern is learnt from the [official doc](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks)):

```
import { connect, __getMockConnection } from '../Database'
//                ^^^^ getting type error here 
import { runSomeQuery } from '../index'

jest.mock('../Database')

test('runSomeQuery', async () => {
  await runSomeQuery()
  const mockConnection = __getMockConnection()
  expect(connect).toBeCalled()
  expect(mockConnection.query).toBeCalledWith('SOME QUERY')
  expect(mockConnection.query).toBeCalledWith('SOME QUERY')
})
```

The test case does pass as expected, but I'm getting this TypeScript error

```
Module '"/project/path/Database"' has no exported member '__getMockConnection'. [2305]
```

TypeScript doesn't know that I'm importing `Database` from the mock. Also for this reason I have to disable the diagnostics of ts-jest which complains the same issue.

How can I solve this? Change the import path to `'../__mocks__/Database'` doesn't work.

Here is the repo: https://github.com/CodinCat/ts-jest-mock-issue

Open `__tests__/index.spec.ts` with an editor that supports TypeScript like VS Code and you will see the error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since typescript is not aware of `jest` mocking, you will need to manually type cast whenever your mocks are different than your actual code:

```
import * as MockDatabase from "../__mocks__/Database";
import * as Database from "../Database";

import { runSomeQuery } from "../index";
jest.mock("../Database");

// Type cast since Database is automatically mocked by jest
const { connect, __getMockConnection } = Database as typeof MockDatabase;

test("runSomeQuery", async () => {
  await runSomeQuery();
  const mockConnection = __getMockConnection();
  expect(connect).toBeCalled();
  expect(mockConnection.query).toBeCalledWith("SOME QUERY");
});
```

Comment: If change the import to `../__mocks__/Database` then the database mock will not be used at all. `index.ts` will import the real `Database.ts` and both line 10 and 11 will fail.

Comment: @CodinCat I finally understand what you meant :) updated the answer which seems to work on my end, hope it helps!

Comment: @CodinCat have you tried this? does the answer make sense?

Answer (score 0):

**Update 29 Sept 2022:**

The [`mocked` function has been integrated into jest](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestmockedsource-options) and is [not available in ts-jest anymore](https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest/pull/3333).

---

Original answer:

Another option is to use [ts-jest](https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest/blob/master/docs/user/test-helpers.md)'s mocked() helper. The helper will make sure you have access to the mock test methods. For details have a look at the post here: [Import function from a Jest manual mock with Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58639737/import-function-from-a-jest-manual-mock-with-typescript/61358020#61358020)

Comment: I'd delete this, that package is no longer around.