# Import function from a Jest manual mock with Typescript

Tags: typescript, mocking, jestjs

I'm creating a custom mock (of an ES6 class) with Jest in a Typescript project. The mock creates end exports a few `mock.fn()` so that they could be spied on in the test suite.

An example could be the official one from the Jest documentation (https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks#manual-mock). There the `SoundPlayer` class has been mocked, as it is its only method `playSoundFile`. The method is mocked using a `jest.fn()`, which is exported to be used in tests.

```js
// soundPlayer.ts
export default class SoundPlayer {
  foo: string = 'bar';

  playSoundFile(filename: string) {
    console.log(`Playing sound file ${filename}`);
  }
}
```

```js
// __mocks__/soundPlayer.ts
export const mockPlaySoundFile = jest.fn();

const mock = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
  return { playSoundFile: mockPlaySoundFile };
});

export default mock;
```

```js
// __tests__/soundPlayer.ts
import SoundPlayer, { mockPlaySoundFile } from '../soundPlayer';

jest.mock('../soundPlayer');

beforeEach(() => {
  mockPlaySoundFile.mockClear();
});

it('is called with filename', () => {
  const filename = 'song.mp3';
  const soundPlayer = new SoundPlayer();
  soundPlayer.playSoundFile(filename);

  expect(mockPlaySoundFile).toBeCalledWith(filename);
});
```

The test works as expected, but TS notifies an error (which kind of makes sense to me) when trying to import the mocked `mockPlaySoundFile` function. That is because, obviously, `mockPlaySoundFile` doesn't exist in `soundPlayer.ts`. But because of `jest.mock('../soundPlayer');` the mock is imported under the hood, therefore the export does exist.

Is there a way to inform TS to look at the mocks in cases like this?

Comment: This thread has a lot of good examples on how to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48759035/mock-dependency-in-jest-with-typescript

You could use the `mocked` helper from ts-jest: https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest/blob/master/docs/user/test-helpers.md

Answer (score 5):

**Update 29 Sept 2022:**

The [`mocked` function has been integrated into jest](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestmockedsource-options) and is [not available in ts-jest anymore](https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest/pull/3333).

---

Original answer:

The easiest way to fix this is to use [ts-jest](https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest/blob/master/docs/user/test-helpers.md)'s `mocked()` helper. The helper will make sure you have access to the mock test methods. `__tests__/soundPlayer.ts` would then look as follows:

```
// __tests__/soundPlayer.ts
import { mocked } from "ts-jest/utils";
import SoundPlayer from '../soundPlayer';

jest.mock('../soundPlayer');

const soundPlayer = mocked(new SoundPlayer());

beforeEach(() => {
  soundPlayer.playSoundFile.mockClear();
});

it('is called with filename', () => {
  const filename = 'song.mp3';

  soundPlayer.playSoundFile(filename);

  expect(soundPlayer.playSoundFile).toBeCalledWith(filename);
});
```

If you really want to include `mockPlaySoundFile` you could do it by telling the Typescript compiler to suppresses the import error:

```
// @ts-ignore
import { mockPlaySoundFile } from '../soundPlayer';
```

Also, have a look at the example in my repo here: https://github.com/tbinna/ts-jest-mock-examples, in particular, your `soundPlayer` example: https://github.com/tbinna/ts-jest-mock-examples/tree/master/sound-player

Comment: I get an error `cannot find module 'ts-jest/utils'`

Comment: Same here @FiddleFreak! Did you find it? I cannot find any documentation for v28 for this helper.

Comment: `// @ts-ignore import { mockPlaySoundFile } ...` is exactly what I needed, thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and I only have a workaround. My problem is that I manually mock fs from node.

So I have a manual mock for 'fs' which looks roughly like this:

```
const fs = jest.genMockFromModule("fs");

let mockFiles = {};

function __clearMocks(){
    mockFiles = {};
}

module.exports = fs;
```

So clearly when my test case imports fs it would not work:

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
fs.__clearMocks();
```

To get this working I create an extension of the type:

```
declare module 'fs' {
    export function __clearMocks(): void; 
}
```

So now I can modify my testcase like this:

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
import 'fsExtension';
fs.__clearMocks();
```

Hopefully this helps you!